# Jquery - acceder a un atributo "data"

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5, php5

tengo un link donde le asigno el atributo "formid" para después obtenerlo desde un botón, lo hago de esta manera

El link genero de esta forma

```
<a class="btnAssign" data-formid="{{$form->id}}" href="#">Asignar personas</a>
```

Luego tengo una "div" oculta que cuando le doy al botón anterior (click) se muestra, y tiene este código

```
<div>
Empleados <br>

<form id="employeeAccess">
@foreach($employees as $employee)

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="employees" value={{ $employee->id }}>
        <label>{{ $employee->name }} ({{ $employee->email }})</label><br/>
    </div>

@endforeach

    <input type="button" id="btnAssign" value="Asignar personas">
</form>
```

Y desde jquery he probado a acceder al valor de data-formid del link, de esta forma

```
    $('#btnAssign').click(function(event){

        var form_uuid = $(this).attr('formid');
        alert($(this).attr("data-formid"));
        alert($(this).data("data-formid"));
    });
```

Adjunto una imagen, aquí muestro un listado con "N" items que son "formularios" y cada item tiene un botón de "Asignar usuarios" que es un link (a href), y lo que hago es abrir una capa (div) encima del bloque de código mostrado, donde allí muestro una serie de checbox y el botón de "Asignar usuarios", es en este botón donde quiero cojer el valor data-formid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: Hola el problema es que estás usando mal el selector `$('#btnAssign').click(function(event){...` es incorrecto porque usa un ID de elemento y tu estás identificando los *anchors* mediante clases debes usar `$('.btnAssign')` para referirte a ellos. Y, la forma correcta de referirte al atributo data es `$(this).attr("data-formid")`

Comment: Adjunto una imagen en el post principal, con la explicación de las 2 acciones que tengo, una es el link (a href) y la otra es el botón (button)

Comment: Pregunto para estar seguro de haber entendido antes de dar pasos en falso: ¿Necesitas poder recoger el id del usuario (o los usuarios) cuyo checkbox esté marcado y actuar usándolo cuando haces click en asignar usuarios? - mi comentario anterior respondía a la ubicación de data-formid en `<a class="btnAssign" data-formid="{{$form->id}}" href="#">Asignar personas</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, el atributo que estas señalando corresponde al uso de un `dataset` (mayor información sobre los [atributos de datos (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) y [manipulación de dataset con jquery](https://api.jquery.com/data/))

```
<a class="btnAssign" data-formid="{{$form->id}}" href="#">Asignar personas</a>
```

Tambien lo que veo, es que al momento de realizar el evento `click` estas haciendo referencia a un id y no la clase de `.btnAssign`

Para ver el valor que esta tomando el dataset `formid` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
   $('.btnAssign').on('click',function(event){
        alert($(this).data("formid"));
    });
```

Con la función `.data()` de jquery, accedemos al valor asignado a la variable.

Aquí un ejemplo simple para que veas como funciona:

```js
$(function(){

    $('.btnAssign').on('click',function(event){
        alert($(this).data("formid"));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btnAssign" data-formid="123" href="#">Asignar personas</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues podrias usar un id o clase para el elemento donde deseas capturar, ya que con this estas capturando el data-formid del button y este no tiene  ningun atributo asi, por eso alerta como undefined.

Seria algo asi:

```js
$('#btnAssign').click(function(event) {

  var form_uuid = $(this).attr('formid');
  alert($(".btnAssign").attr("data-formid"));
  alert($("#captura").attr("data-formid"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btnAssign" id="captura" data-formid="{{$form->id}}" href="#">Asignar personas</a>
<div>
  Empleados <br>

  <form id="employeeAccess">
    @foreach($employees as $employee)

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="employees" value={{ $employee->id }}>
      <label>{{ $employee->name }} ({{ $employee->email }})</label><br/>
    </div>

    @endforeach

    <input type="button" id="btnAssign" value="Asignar personas">
  </form>
```

Comment: Gracias, he adjuntado una imagen en el post principal, con la explicación de las 2 acciones que tengo, una es el link (a href) y la otra es el botón (button)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estás ejecutando el evento sobre el elemento equivocado, al hacer esto:

```js
    $('#btnAssign').click(function(event){

        var form_uuid = $(this).attr('formid');
        alert($(this).attr("data-formid"));
        alert($(this).data("data-formid"));
    });
```

Estás creando el evento sobre `#btnAssign`, que vendría a ser tu botón para asignar personas (`<input type="button" id="btnAssign" value="Asignar personas">`).

Lo que deberías hacer sería:

```js
    $('.btnAssign').click(function(event){

        var form_uuid = $(this).attr('formid');
        alert($(this).attr("data-formid"));
        alert($(this).data("data-formid"));
    });
```

Para poder crear el evento sobre el link que contiene ese atributo `data-formid`, debes llamarlo sobre `.btnAssign`.